# WinForms Button Click event and similar events depend on focus

Tags: c#, winforms, button, focus, tabcontrol

I have the next situation:

- there is a client app with a `Form`
- the `Form` contains a few `TabControl`'s
- there are different controls on `TabPage`'s of `TabControl`'s
- when the user clicks on any control, I need to activate the `TabPage` that is a parent of a control. For that I use a `TabPage` `Enter` event
- when the `TabPage` gets activated, I need to make request to the server app, and I put focus to a hidden `TextBox` to disable UI

The problem is, when I click on a `Button` on another `TabPage`, in `TabPage`.`Enter` event handler I take focus to my hidden `TextBox`, and it seems like `Button` click event doesn't have enough time to be processed. When I put timer and handle `TabPage`.`Enter` event after 100 ms, the `Button` click event seems to be fired well. Same thing happens to all the controls: `CheckBox` doesn't get checked, `RadioButton` too. I wouldn't like to use timer, as that is not a stable solution.

Any ideas how could I make `TabPage` to process all mouse events before I take focus to hidden `TextBox`? I tried to use `Application.DoEvents()`, but that didn't help.

Comment: You are using a wrong event for what you're trying to do. Instead, use `Selecting` or `Selected` event of a `TabControl`, depending on whether you want to cancel changing a tab for any reason or not.

Comment: Thank you, but that wouldn't fit my needs. `Selecting` or `Selected` event of `TabControl` don't get fired when you don't change the active page. Let's say focus is in 1 of the `TabControl`'s, and I press on a `Button` of an active `TabPage` of another `TabControl`. Then the active page in total changes, but the `Selected` event is not fired of course.

Comment: Are you talking about `TabControl` nested inside another `TabControl` or multiple `TabControl`s side by side?

Comment: Multiple, side by side.

Comment: Then my answer still applies but you need to use `Enter` and `Leave` events of `TabControl`s to get notified when you change from one to another.

Comment: But if a `Button` is on an active `TabPage` of inactive `TabControl`, and I press on a `Button`, wich event should I use to make a request to a server app? `Selected` doesn't get fired, `Enter` doesn't fit.

Comment: Answer has been updated related to previous comments

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrong event for a wrong control for what you are trying to do.

`Enter` event for `TabPage` is going to be fired when that page becomes an active control of the current form which might not happen under certain conditions. Instead, you need to use `Selecting` or `Selected` event of `TabControl`, depending on whether you want to cancel switching to a different tab or not (see [`TabControlCancelEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.TabControlCancelEventArgs(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter of `Selecting` event). In your case, `Selecting` event would be more appropriate since it won't allow switching to a selected tab until event is complete (unless you're doing an asynchronous request to the server). Additionally, you may no longer need to use the hidden TextBox.

**UPDATE**

Regarding comments to OP, when you have 2 (or more) `TabControl`s on a form and you want to get notified when you press a button in any tab of a different `TabControl`, you can use `Enter` event for `TabControl`. Use a global variable to store which `TabControl` was activated in the `Enter` event and then send server request for a currently active tab of that activate `TabControl`.

If this doesn't work for your scenario, then you need to carefully examine your workflow and see if it can be improved in relation to what you want to accomplish.

Comment: You can see my comment above. I need an event that would mean that an active page of all the `Form` changed.

Comment: Thank you, @LightBulb, but I can't generate my server request in a `TabControl`'s `Enter` event. I'll try to carefully examine my workflow as you suggested. If anyone else has another suggestions, feel free to share :)